# Xamarin Forms Create Conditions for Labels/ListView Creation

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

My application organizes user input into various lists to create an organized grocery list. For example, if the user enters "apples" the app will add that to the FruitList. Once all items have been added, the program will display each list on the next page (so similar items are grouped together). I want the second page to create "sections" (currently a label and a ListView) for each category only if its corresponding list contains items. I have created a condition that sets the label's IsVisible property to false if a list contains no items, but the section still takes up blank space on the page. How do I go about either reducing the size of a section or eliminating it altogether if it does not have items associated with it? Below is some sample code from my XAML view and its ViewModel. Thanks

View:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:OrganizedViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Fruit" FontSize="Large"
                   IsVisible="{Binding CheckFruit}"/>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding OFruitList}"/>

            <Label Text="Vegetables" FontSize="Large"
                   IsVisible="{Binding CheckVegetable}"/>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding OVegetableList}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

ViewModel:

```
class OrganizedViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> OFruitList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> OVegetableList { get; set; }
    public bool CheckFruit { get; set; }
    public bool CheckVegetable { get; set; }

    public OrganizedViewModel()
    {
        OFruitList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        OVegetableList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        GetOrganizedList();
        CheckFruit = CheckList(OFruitList);
        CheckVegetable = CheckList(OVegetableList);
    }

    void GetOrganizedList()
    {
        foreach (string value in Categories.FruitList)
        {
            OFruitList.Add(value);
        }
        foreach (string value in Categories.VegetableList)
        {
            OVegetableList.Add(value);
        }
    }

    public bool CheckList(ObservableCollection<string> value)
    {
        if (value.Any())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: "Categories.FruitList" and "Categories.VegetableList" are string lists populated on the previous page.

Comment: this seems like a good place to use a grouped ListView

Comment: I guess binding the `IsVisible` property of `ListView`s as well, will remove the extra space you mentioned.

Comment: You could leverage the built in [ListView Grouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#grouping) functionality rather than implementing your own display rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, according to your description,we recommend you use  [Grouping ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#grouping) to achieve this.

When `grouping` is activated for a ListView, a header row is added for each group.
To enable grouping:

- Create a list of lists (a list of groups, each group being a list of
  elements).
- Set the ListView's `ItemsSource` to that list.
- Set `IsGroupingEnabled` to true.
- Set `[GroupDisplayBinding][2]` to bind to the property of the groups that is
  being used as the title of the group.
- [Optional] Set [GroupShortNameBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.groupshortnamebinding?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_ListView_GroupShortNameBinding) to bind to the property of the
  groups that is being used as the short name for the group. The short
  name is used for the jump lists (right-side column on iOS).

For more details, you can refer to docuemnt:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#grouping .

In addition , you can also use [Xamarin.Forms CollectionView Grouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping) to achieve this.

**Note:** There are samples included in above two documents, you can check them.

Comment: Thanks so much for everyone's suggestions! I'll try out the Grouping ListView

Comment: Not yet, but I'm pretty sure that this solution is going to work. I'm still new to Xamarin and MVVM in general, and I'm having a bit of trouble populating the various lists now. I changed the lists to a class property called "Items" so I could bind the TextCell Detail to it, but the lists aren't populating the way they used to.

Comment: Could you please post more code snippets so that we can help you better?

Comment: I've actually got it working now. I made a new post after I played around with the grouping a bit and had a better idea of what I was having trouble with. I ended up changing my model to be a collection that also had a "type" property I used for grouping. Here's the link to the other post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68674287/xamarin-forms-listview-grouping-contents-not-binding). Thanks again!